# Querying Sharepoint Online From C# CSOM Console App

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am attempting to query SharePoint Online using CSOM but I am getting this error -> what do I need to change in my project to remove this error so I can succesfully query?

> System.InvalidCastException: '[A]Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem. Type A originates from 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a byte array. Type B originates from 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a byte array.'

**EDIT**
Sometimes this will throw the above error and other times it executes exactly as I would expect.  I would like to nail down what is causing the error so it can be removed :)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string an = "Jose Mendez";
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => CaptureData1(an));
    var task2 = Task.Run(() => CaptureData2(an));

    var dbval = task1.Result;
    string b = task2.Result;
}

private static DBData CaptureData1(string manager)
{
    string a = null;
    string b = null;
    string c = null;
    string d = null;

    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(URL1))
    {
        var web = ctx.Web;
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(Site1);
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("");

        var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

        ctx.Load(listItemCollection, eachItem => eachItem.Include(item => item));

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach(ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
        {

        }
        var dbval = new DBData
        {

        };
        return dbval;
    }
}
private static string CaptureData2(string manager)
{
    string transID = null;

    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(URL2))
    {
        var web = ctx.Web;
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(Site2);
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("");

        var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

        ctx.Load(listItemCollection, eachItem => eachItem.Include(item => item, item => item["X"]));

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
        {
            transID = listItem["X"].ToString();
        }
        return transID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: @sasfrog -> removed sensitive data and posted code

Answer (score 1):

This seems cause by DLL conflict, try to install the dll by [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM) and try.

Screenshot from VS2013 for your reference.

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution and I still get the issue described in my OP.  It is random and I can see no rhyme or reason as to why it is thrown on attempt 1 but not attempt 2 for example.